# Issue with passing python dict to c++ as map

Tags: boost-python

I have a c++ class exported to python using,

```
class_<std::map<std::string, std::string> >("str2str_map")
        .def(map_indexing_suite< std::map<std::string, std::string> > ());

class_< MyClass, boost::noncopyable >("MyClass")
    .def(init<>())
    .def("process", &MyClass::process )
```

with the function signature,

```
void MyClass::process(std::map<std::string, std::string> & queryMap)
```

However when i try to call from the python side, I get the error,

> Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>       MyClass.process(MyClass, dict, function, int) did not match C++ signature:
>       process(MyClass{lvalue}, std::map,
>   std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >,
>   std::less,
>   std::allocator > >,
>   std::allocator, std::allocator > const,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > > > > {lvalue})

What do i need to do to make it work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to use const param? void MyClass::process(**const** std::map<std::string, std::string> & queryMap); If that does not help provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hmm ok let me give it a try...